# How to click a link in win32com.client IE?

Tags: python, internet-explorer

I'm using `win32com.client` to control an IE instance in Python. How can I click a link on a certain page (e.g. using navigate to link href isn't acceptable since it won't trigger referrer sending)?

Here is the base:

```
import random
import time
from win32com.client import Dispatch

ie = Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.visible = 1

ie.navigate('http://digg.com')

while (ie.ReadyState != 4):
    time.sleep(0.05)

hrefs = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("A")
href = hrefs[random.randrange(hrefs.length)]
#How to click this one?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it has `.click()` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535173(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `Headers` parameter of the `navigate` method to manually set the Referrer header like:

> Referrer: http://example.com

Comment: well, what if, say the link goes not to it's href thanks to some JS function? in this case the browser would navigate to a page it wouldn't visit if there was a user

Comment: Good point cheating in the manner I suggested would only work in limited circumstances.